# Is there any simple program to generate a class for JSON data binding for Windows 8 app?

Tags: c#, windows-8

I am working on a large JSON data for a windows 8 app which is quite complex. In .net we can bind the class to get the data populate after parsing the JSON. But for that we need a precis JSON data class. It very hard for me to get the Class right. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate class
Using http://json2csharp.net by copying the entire JSON data string.

Then

```
  public async Task<string>getData()
       {
          HttpClient client=new HttpClient();
    String URL="your string";//url for the JSON response
    HttpResponseMessage response=await client.GetAsync(URL);
    Return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

   private void async Button1_click ()
   {
      string responseText= await getData();
DataContractJsonSerializer= new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeOf(RootObject));//DataContractJsonSerializer is the class object that u will generate 
RootObject root;
Using(MemoryStream stream=new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(responseText)))
{
    //access properties here
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**json2csharp**](http://json2csharp.com/) to generate classes from json